# Pandas column addition/subtraction

Tags: python, pandas

I am using a pandas/python dataframe.  I am trying to do a lag subtraction.

I am currently using:

```
newCol = df.col - df.col.shift()
```

This leads to a NaN in the first spot:

```
NaN
45
63
23
...
```

First question:  Is this the best way to do a subtraction like this?

Second:  If I want to add a column (same number of rows) to this new column.  Is there a way that I can make all the NaN's 0's for the calculation?

Ex:

```
col_1 = 
Nan
45
63
23

col_2 = 
10
10
10
10

new_col = 
10
55
73
33
```

and NOT

```
NaN
55
73
33
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think your method of of computing lags is just fine:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(range(4), columns = ['col'])

print(df['col'] - df['col'].shift())
# 0   NaN
# 1     1
# 2     1
# 3     1
# Name: col

print(df['col'] + df['col'].shift())
# 0   NaN
# 1     1
# 2     3
# 3     5
# Name: col
```

If you wish `NaN` plus (or minus) a number to be the number (not `NaN`), use the `add` (or `sub`) method with `fill_value = 0`:

```
print(df['col'].sub(df['col'].shift(), fill_value = 0))
# 0    0
# 1    1
# 2    1
# 3    1
# Name: col

print(df['col'].add(df['col'].shift(), fill_value = 0))
# 0    0
# 1    1
# 2    3
# 3    5
# Name: col
```